# Airflow parameter passing

Tags: bash, airflow

I have a simple job that I'd like to move under an Airflow process, if possible. As it stands, I have a string of bash scripts that access a server and download the latest version of a file and then perform a variety of downstream manipulations to that file.

```
exec ./somescript.sh somefileurl
```

What I'd like to know is: how can I pass in the URL to this file every time I need to run this process?

It seems that if I try to run the bash script as a bash command like so:

```
download = BashOperator(
task_id='download_release',
bash_command='somescript.sh',
# params={'URL': 'somefileurl'},
dag=dag)
```

I have no way of passing in the one parameter that the bash script requires. Otherwise, if I try to send the bash script in as a bash command like so:

```
download = BashOperator(
task_id='download_release',
bash_command='./somescript.sh {{ URL }}',
params={'URL': 'somefileurl'},
dag=dag)
```

I receive an execution error as the program tries to execute the script in the context of a temporary directory. This breaks the script as it requires access to some credentials files that sit in the same directory and I'd like to keep the relative file locations intact...

Thoughts?

### Update: What worked for me

```
download = BashOperator(
task_id='download_release',
bash_command='cd {{ params.dir }} && ./somescript.sh {{ params.url }}',
params={'url': 'somefileurl',
        'dir': 'somedir'},
dag=dag)
```

I did not implement any parameter passing yet, though.

Comment: Where's the edit button?! The URL changes daily, hence the need to input it 'manually'.

Comment: Speaking as someone who knows bash but not airflow, this looks like very unfortunate design decision on the latter's part -- unless they provide a way to do a shell-less execve()-style invocation of an exact argv list, or to perform POSIX sh-compliant escaping, you're going to be necessarily vulnerable to shell injection attacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of passing a parameter to your BashOperator:

```
templated_command = """
cd /working_directory
somescript.sh {{ dag_run.conf['URL'] }}
"""
download = BashOperator(
   task_id='download_release',
   bash_command=templated_command,
   dag=dag)
```

For a discussion about this see [passing parameters to externally trigged dag](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/airbnb_airflow/GRdoW30PNUI). Airflow has two example DAG's that demonstrate this: [example_trigger_controller_dag](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_trigger_controller_dag.py) and [example_trigger_target_dag](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_trigger_target_dag.py).  Also, see the [Airflow api reference on macros](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/code.html#macros).

Comment: Ok to the parameter passing however, doesn't that templated `bash_command` still execute in a temporary directory somewhere in the bowels of my machine? It seems similar to my second example which doesn't execute in the local directory

Comment: I didn't catch that part of the problem was the BashOperator running in a temporary directory. Somewhat of a hack but you could pass a templated command with the first line changing to the directory that you need. I have edited the answer to show this.  Another option would be to create your own operator that ran the bash process in the current directory.

Comment: As someone who knows Airflow, could you speak to how to avoid shell injection attacks here? (If we have an untrusted parameter, how do we pass it safely?)

Comment: ...which is to say: Let's say that an attacker has run a FTP upload creating a directory identical to that would would be made by the command `mkdir -p /uploads/$'\n$(rm -rf $HOME)\'$(rm -rf $HOME)\'` and something in that directory is being passed to an Airflow process. How do we pass that name out-of-band, such that it's treated only as data and not parsed as code?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy there are a couple of options I can think of to avoid shell injection here.  The first is simply surrounding ```{{ dag_run.conf['URL'] }}``` in quotes so that whatever is passed is treated just as a string instead of potentially some other command.  A more complicated solution would be to create another operator that read in any expected parameters with ```ast.literal_eval``` then pass them to the required bash script.

Comment: @JeremyFarrell, surrounding it in quotes doesn't work -- see my example including literal quotes in the filename. Those will escape any outer single-quotes (and the injection will occur regardless inside double-quotes without any work being needed).

Comment: (oops -- I actually missed a closing syntactic quote in my example; it needs to be `mkdir -p /uploads/$'\n$(rm -rf $HOME)\'$(rm -rf $HOME)\''` -- the backslash-prefixed will be created as literal components of the filename, the others are parts of shell directives. Note that the above is built using extensions available in ksh or bash, and I don't advise running it on any other shell).

Comment: Hmm. Actually, reading the BashOperator docs for Airflow, it looks like it allows environment variables to be passed in. This means one should be able to do something like: `BashOperator=(bash_command='cd "$directory" && somescript.sh "$url", env: { 'PATH': '/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin', 'directory': directoryVariableHere, 'url': urlVariableHere})`, and have the directory and url passed in out-of-band from the code.

Comment: ...might I suggest following that practice here, if my reading is correct and it's a functional/working approach?